# Not able to start SQL Server Reporting Service Application on SharePoint-2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I have a problem to create SQL Server Reporting Service Application. When I try to create it through an error `*"Could not find SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\110 registry key"*`

The status of SQL Server Reporting Service is **Error Starting** under Application Management->Manage Services on server. If I try to start forcefully it through same error "`*Could not find SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\110 registry key*`".

I have Two Servers

SQL Server 2012 with SP2 on Server A and SharePoint-2013 on Server B.

I tried with installing reporting services 2012 sp2 add-in on SharePoint Server(Server B)

Even I cant see "Report Server Integration Feature" under Site setting ->Site collection features.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you download the SQL Server® 2012 SP2 Reporting Services Add-in for Microsoft® SharePoint and install it then there are cases it won't create registry key.

To fix Use the SQL Server installation .iso select the RS Add-in for SharePoint from the feature selection.

read more here: https://richmintzbi.wordpress.com/2014/03/08/ssrs-sharepoint-2013-create-service-application-error-could-not-find-softwaremicrosoftmicrosoft-sql-server110-registry-key-error/

also check this http://blog.sharepointsite.co.uk/2013/07/installing-ssrs-2012-in-sharepoint-mode.html